# js works, up until including it from another file

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I have a small, simple js function (using vuejs) that works when coded into my blade file, but when I try to include it from a different js file, it doesn't.

basically;

```
<script> //here is my script </script>
```

works, but

```
<script src="/includes/samescriptbutinjsfile.js"> </script>
```

does not work.

I've tried loading this js-file both in my header and in the bottom of my body. To provide more context I'm trying to make this easy method from the vue.js introduction work;

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'this is a message'
    }
})
```

in the top part of my body I have a div

```
<div id="app">
    @{{ message }}
</div>
// some other divs
// and here the script/scriptcall to file
```

I'm clueless to what's posing a problem here..

Comment: do your include <script> in master.blade before closing <body> tag ?

Comment: @SabaTandashvili yes, the script is included between the last div's closing bracket and the body's closing bracket

Comment: Is the path correct? Check Chrome DevTools console to see any errors.

Comment: @Stretsh I previously got RunTimeErrors when I src='d it to a wrong path. I'll try and see where it lands - edit: the path looks to be correct, it accepts it as a path, but returns an empty file. as if nothing is writtin in it.

Comment: Have you tried the old fashioned `../includes/` I assume that Includes/ is within your public folder

Comment: My next step would be to view the page source and follow the link of the script, to see what the browser sees. Then verify if this is the right file.

Comment: @Option and what should I be seeing? It gives me an empty block of script too, which leads me to believe something does go wrong with my src. -- the includes directory is in project/app/includes, as I was told to do, as js shouldn't be in the public directory?

Comment: Uhm, JS should be in the public dir... Same as the CSS and Images etc.. The only thing you don't put in the public dir is code. With Laravel it'll automatically be looking within public/ for the file therefore it won't work if it's not in there.

Comment: @Option alright then. I dropped my .js file into the js directory in the public directory, altered the src path to /public/js/file.js - sameold. no js is found when checking the pagesource. It accepts the path and seemingly includes the file, but doesn't show the script written ín the file

Comment: Whats the src you're running now? try `<script src="../folder/samescriptbutinjsfile.js">` - Don't add `/public/` as it looks into the public folder by default

Comment: @Option the src as is now is src="public/js/display.js" , if I remove public (as you say), phpstorm notifies me that "Cannot resolve directory 'js' ". My src path would then be src="/js/display.js"

Comment: If it's running laravel it will automatically pick it up regardless.. Try `src="../js/display.js"`

Comment: @Option if you throw it into an answerbox I'll mark it. `src="../js/display.js"` does the trick, even though phpstorm tells me the directory can't be resolved. That's what threw me off of even trying. Thanks a lot !

Comment: I assumed you had it in public. Since you're working in blade, you could easily also do <script src={{ asset('js/display.js></script>.

Comment: @Ciphra, I have added it in for you. It can be a pain but at least you have also learnt it must stay within the public folder :)

Comment: @Option thanks for the advice! I've been scrounging about, looking for tutorials about the combination between vue and laravel, where one of them said js should be in (for example) an includes directory, because having it in public was something "you shouldn't do". Again, thanks for the advice and the friendly tone

Comment: Check out Laracasts. Very good place to get started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, it's because you're including into another folders file so your include needs to go up a level to fetch the relevant file being called.

The easiest way is to simply change: `src="js/display.js"` to `src="../js/display.js"`

Answer (score 0):

The "Laravel way" to do this would be to use asset: `src={{ asset('js/display.js') }}`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-asset